# 64bit rpm can not resolve 32bit dependencies

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

**Problem**

I'm having a RPM that contains mixed 64bit and 32bit binaries. One of the binaries depends on 32bit i686 packages. When I try to install the package yum gives me an error, noting that the package requires the 32bit packages. However when I just try to install the required packages myself it works flawless.

**Details**

In my spec file I have

```
Requires:       glibc.i686 libstdc++.i686 device-mapper-libs.i686 lshw
```

When I try to install the package on a CentOS 6.3 system I get:

```
# yum update gamigo-kvm-tools
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gamigo-kvm-tools.x86_64 0:0.0.7-4 will be updated
---> Package gamigo-kvm-tools.x86_64 0:0.0.9-4 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libstdc++.i686 for package: gamigo-kvm-tools-0.0.9-4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc.i686 for package: gamigo-kvm-tools-0.0.9-4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: device-mapper-libs.i686 for package: gamigo-kvm-tools-0.0.9-4.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gamigo-kvm-tools-0.0.9-4.x86_64 (gamigo-CentOS-6-x86_64-liv)
           Requires: libstdc++.i686
Error: Package: gamigo-kvm-tools-0.0.9-4.x86_64 (gamigo-CentOS-6-x86_64-liv)
           Requires: device-mapper-libs.i686
Error: Package: gamigo-kvm-tools-0.0.9-4.x86_64 (gamigo-CentOS-6-x86_64-liv)
           Requires: glibc.i686
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

However when I manually install the referenced packages, I get

```
# yum install libstdc++.i686 device-mapper-libs.i686 glibc.i686
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Package libstdc++-4.4.6-4.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Package device-mapper-libs-1.02.74-10.el6.i686 already installed and latest version
Package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

I don't quite understand why the Error occurs and what it's trying to tell me. I see that it's only occurring for the 32bit packages as the fourth required package 'lshw' seems to be no problem. Is there a special specfile syntax to reference 32bit packages?

Comment: Contact the packager and report the two bugs.

Comment: I am the packager myself, and it's not a bug. You just reference 32bit libraries in a spec file differently than you would on the shell.

Comment: AFAIR, RPM has never supported "several architectures" packages. I believe your `.i?86` dependencies are wrong, and perhaps are the cause of your problems. Also, libraries are autodetected as dependencies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just found the answer. My Requires line should be

```
Requires:       glibc(x86-32) libstdc++(x86-32) device-mapper-libs(x86-32)
```

as described in
http://www.rpm.org/wiki/PackagerDocs/ArchDependencies

Comment: This just shows how awesome serverfault is. You post a question and in 12 minutes you have a detailed and precise answer!

Comment: Especially if you find the answer yourself :-P   ...had I searched 12 min. longer before asking on serverfault, I might not have posted the question at all. Than again, it might be useful for others with the same problem.

Comment: Should note that specifying requirement arch. using round brackets only works on rpmbuild version > 4.6... Still have not found how to do it in 4.4

Answer (score 0):

Since somebody answered for answered for 4.6 -- for the 4.4 version, if you depend on a 32bit RPM a way around difficulties or lack of syntax that may work for others:

```
Requires:      /lib/libc.so.6
```

Since this file gets provided by the 32bit of glibc the installation will pull in the correct dependency.